# Switching the position of two HTML elements with Javascript/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, google-tag-manager

We have a few HTML elements near the bottom of our page that aren't being used much. We want to do some testing with Google Tag Manager to switch these elements with some that are near the top of the page. Is it possible with plain JS or CSS to switch the position of two HTML elements? For example, let's say I want to switch the positions of div1 and div3:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
    <span>3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add some examples of the code that you are using and add some of the steps for things that you have already tried?

Comment: It is possible using flexbox in css

Comment: To switch the position of elements, you can use the order property inside flexbox

Answer (score 3):

You can use the flexbox of css like this to switch the positions of child contents.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.div1 {
  order: 3;
}

.div3 {
  order: 1;
}

.div2 {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
    <span>3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```